# How to read a string word by word

Tags: string, vbscript, cpu-word

I have a VBScript that reads the name of users from a txt file. The user names come from a long string of the directory and some additional info after. Using VBS I got to delete the first part and the last part of the line from the text file to only read the name.

Now, my variable (`strName`) will give me something like: `"john doe"`. My end goal is to transform this into an e-mail address. The domain is always the same, so I need to be able to start with `"john doe"` and end up with `"john.doe@gmail.com"` (Not going to specify the actual domain as it`s irrelevant to the question). Right now I was able to add the`"@gmail.com"` to the string, but I have no idea how to do the rest.

I'm thinking of reading the first name into a new variable `strFirstName` and the last name in a second `strLastName` and then adding a line along the lines of:

```
strName = strFirstName + "." + strLastName + "@gmail.com"
```

What can I use to read only one word at a time? I used the following function in the script to be able to get the name, but since the length of the name can vary, I can't use the same thing for this.

```
strName = Mid(strName, 4 + 11)
strName = Left(strName, (LEN(strName)-13))
```

Comment: What does your source string look like? Does it just have spaces between words or are other characters present?

Comment: The source string starts off by looking like:
"C:\Directory\John Doe\OS - Information"

     .After running the two lines at the end of my original post, the string now is: John Doe. All there is is a space between the John and the Doe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your source string is always in the form:

```
C:\Directory\first last\OS - Information
```

Then you can extract the first and last names using a few `Split()`s:

```
strSource = "C:\Directory\John Doe\OS - Information"
strName  = Split(strSource, "\")(2)
strFirst = Split(strName)(0)
strLast  = Split(strName)(1)
```

The first `Split()` separates your string by `\`, creating 4 elements. Since you only care about the third one (index `2`), you can just append `(2)` to return just that string.

Now that we have `John Doe`, just use `Split()` again (the space character is the default) to extract the first and last names.

Now you can create your e-mail address:

```
strEmail = strFirst & "." & strLast & "@gmail.com"
```

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much for your help! It`s greatly appreciated